# Adjoint of Exponential Map

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry, adjoint-operators

If $\exp: T_p(G) \rightarrow G$ is the expoenential map of a lie group, then what does the adjoint operator (as in $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,A^*,y\rangle$) of the derivative of exp look like?

i.e: $d_v\exp_p(v)$ and $d_p\exp_p(v)$?

Is is Related to ad?

(Sorry if this is an obvious question but I've always wondered).

For example: on the before last page in [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5133-probabilistic-principal-geodesic-analysis.pdf) the authors derive an expression for these, do these arise from $S^n$'s Lie structure?

Comment: $\exp$ is a map $T_{\text{id}} G \to G$. Anyway, the operator adjoint to what?

Comment: The adjoint of the derivative of exp, so $d_vexp_p(v)$ and $d_pexp_p(v)$?